# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry on empty database LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to register a user  and this happens:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_nif_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (paco, 2020-05-03 15:16:09, 2020-05-03 15:16:09))

The database is empty and I check it if laravel was checking the same database as I am.

It's also strange that only takes the name in the form.

```
//Register COntroller

 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email:rfc,dns','string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'nif' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'regex:/^[0-9]+$/',  'max:8', 'unique:users'],
            'date_of_birth' =>['required', 'date'],
            'first_name' =>['nullable',  'string', 'min:2'],
            'last_name' =>['nullable',  'string', 'min:2'],
            'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'nif' => $data['nif'] . self::LetraNIF($data['nif']),
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),           
            'date_of_birth' => $data['date_of_birth'],
            'role' => "Usuario",
            'first_name' =>$data['first_name'],
            'last_name' =>$data['last_name'],
        ]);
    }
```

[image: database user]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As always it's my fault.

I didn't edited the users.php to add the different fields.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

First check your users table inis the Id is Auto-increment, if the ID is not auto-increment you'will always get the same errors